# Java Mail API How to get really all Headers

Tags: java, header, jakarta-mail

I want to get all the headers of a mail like in Gmail when clicking on "Show Original". When I use the Message.getAllHeaders method, I don't get all. Most of the messages contain a forwarded mail (I think these headers are not shown). Here's my code:

```
Enumeration headers = message.getAllHeaders();
while(headers.hasMoreElements()){
    Header header = (Header) headers.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Header: " + header.getName());
}
```

Comment: What exact headers are you missing?

Comment: It's a custom header called "X-Memberid". This header is contained mostly in my own sent emails. But I want to read it when I get the original message back as forwarded message. I'm able to see it in Gmail (when I click on "show Original") but not when accessing the headers with the above function.

Comment: If the header you're looking for is the header of an original message that's attached to another message when the original message is forwarded, then you need to find that attachment in the forwarded message, get the content of that attachment (body part) as a Message, and ask for all the headers of that message.  If that doesn't make sense, post the content of the message you see with "show Original".

Comment: Thank you, do you have some code to read (not download) the attachments and fetching a specific header of them, if one exists? Just to be clear: the forwarded message is contained in the new message as text (not a visible attached file like a txt. document or something)

Comment: I get Parts of the mail with content types "message/feedback-report" and "message/rfc822". How can I get those headers?

Comment: `message/rfc822` is what you are looking for.